# Do surjective ring homomorphisms commute with intersection of ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $f:A\longrightarrow B$ be a surjective ring homomorphism. Is it true that for any intersection of ideals, the image of the intersection is equal to the intersection of the images of the ideals?

One containment is trivial.

Edit: In particular the image of the intersection is contained in every image of the ideals individually and hence in the intersection of the images.

Comment: Which containment is it you say is trivial?

Comment: Of course the image of the intersection is a subset of the image of each of the ideals, hence forming intersections is a subset of the intersection of the images. May have been an error on my part to not mention it. Can anyone explain why this has been downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect those who did did it because the question looks like a verbatim copy of a homework assignment with no thoughts of your own added. Such questions are generally disfavored by those who doesn't want the site to be a general do-my-homework-for-me service.

Comment: That is what I tried, next to other examples. I feel sorry my laziness in formulating the question led people to believe I had not thought about it. This question arose by self-reflection and was not given to me as homework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field, let $A=k[x,y]$, let $B=k[z]$, and let $f:A\to B$ be defined by $f(x)=f(y)=z$.

Consider the ideals $I=(x)$ and $J=(y)$ of $A$. Then $I\cap J=(xy)$ so $f(I\cap J)=(z\cdot z)=(z^2)$, whereas $f(I)\cap f(J)=(z)\cap (z)=(z)$. So in this case we have
$$f(I\cap J)\subsetneq f(I)\cap f(J)$$

Comment: Actually you have considered the canonical surjection $k[x,y]\to k[x,y]/(x-y)$. I want to point this out since canonical surjection $R\to R/I$ for $R$ a PID can't be a counterexample, so in some sense your example is "minimal" as long as $k[x,y]$ is not a PID (while $k[x]$ it is).